# Java 11 java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name sun.security.util.Resources, locale en_US when calling jmx Bean

Tags: java, spring, redhat, jmx, java-11

We recently migrated our app to java 11 and we are experiencing issues when using jmx to access mbeans. We used JDK Mission Control and also jmx term (https://docs.cyclopsgroup.org/welcome, it is based on jconsole) to access. MBeans are exposed via Spring (5.2.5.RELEASE).

The same functionality worked fine with java 7 and it looks like it works with java11 adoptjdk (not fully verified on the same conditions, just checked when app runs in Intellij).

It could be some problem with locale we use to run but changing of locale doesn't have any difference.

Environment:
java:
openjdk version "11.0.13" 2021-10-19 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.13+8-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.13+8-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)
Vendor is RedHat

linux:
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server"
VERSION="7.9 (Maipo)"

locale:

```
LANG=C
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_PAPER="C"
LC_NAME="C"
LC_ADDRESS="C"
LC_TELEPHONE="C"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C"
LC_ALL=
```

Exception:

```
    javax.management.RuntimeMBeanException: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name sun.security.util.Resources, locale en_US
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.rethrow(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:829)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.rethrowMaybeMBeanException(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:842)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:811)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1466)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1307)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1406)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:827)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:303)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:279)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:161)
        at jdk.remoteref/jdk.jmx.remote.internal.rmi.PRef.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl_Stub.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector$RemoteMBeanServerConnection.invoke(RMIConnector.java:1021)
        at org.openjdk.jmc.rjmx.internal.MCMBeanServerConnection.invoke(MCMBeanServerConnection.java:258)
        at org.openjdk.jmc.rjmx.internal.MBeanOperationWrapper$1.call(MBeanOperationWrapper.java:104)
        at org.openjdk.jmc.rjmx.ui.operations.ExecuteOperationForm$4.run(ExecuteOperationForm.java:182)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
    Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name sun.security.util.Resources, locale en_US
        at java.base/java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:2055)
        at java.base/java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1689)
        at java.base/java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1582)
        at java.base/java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1556)
        at java.base/java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:857)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1705)
        at java.base/sun.security.util.ResourcesMgr.getBundle(ResourcesMgr.java:54)
        at java.base/sun.security.util.ResourcesMgr.getString(ResourcesMgr.java:40)
        at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.collectionNullClean(Subject.java:1004)
        at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject$SecureSet.containsAll(Subject.java:1279)
        at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject$SecureSet.equals(Subject.java:1382)
        at java.base/java.util.Collections$SynchronizedSet.equals(Collections.java:2143)
        at java.base/javax.security.auth.SubjectDomainCombiner.combine(SubjectDomainCombiner.java:196)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.remote.security.JMXSubjectDomainCombiner.combine(JMXSubjectDomainCombiner.java:71)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessControlContext.optimize(AccessControlContext.java:608)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.getCombinedACC(ProtectionDomain.java:109)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
        at java.management/javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.resolveMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1047)
        at java.management/javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:1005)
        at org.springframework.jmx.export.SpringModelMBean.invoke(SpringModelMBean.java:90)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:809)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1466)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1307)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1406)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:827)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Recursive update
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1760)
        at java.base/sun.security.util.ResourcesMgr.getBundle(ResourcesMgr.java:54)
        at java.base/sun.security.util.ResourcesMgr.getString(ResourcesMgr.java:40)
        at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.collectionNullClean(Subject.java:1004)
        at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject$SecureSet.containsAll(Subject.java:1279)
        at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject$SecureSet.equals(Subject.java:1382)
        at java.base/java.util.Collections$SynchronizedSet.equals(Collections.java:2143)
        at java.base/javax.security.auth.SubjectDomainCombiner.combine(SubjectDomainCombiner.java:196)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.remote.security.JMXSubjectDomainCombiner.combine(JMXSubjectDomainCombiner.java:71)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessControlContext.optimize(AccessControlContext.java:608)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.getContext(AccessController.java:839)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:424)
        at java.base/java.util.ResourceBundle$ResourceBundleProviderHelper.loadResourceBundle(ResourceBundle.java:3602)
        at java.base/java.util.ResourceBundle.loadBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1844)
        at java.base/java.util.ResourceBundle.findBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1774)
        at java.base/java.util.ResourceBundle.findBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1728)
        at java.base/java.util.ResourceBundle.findBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1728)
        at java.base/java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1662)
        ... 42 more
```

Comment: It looks like completely not related to jdk vendor. Checked with Eclipse Adopt openjdk. The same issue.

Comment: How are you building and running the application?  Spring Boot application jar?

Comment: I am building via maven via spring boot maven plugin and using fat jar to start. I have found the problem. I will share soon and answer for my question.